# ¿Cómo comparar una hora específica contra la del sistema?

Tags: excel, condiciones, while, vb

Quiero hacer una comparación de hora con un **IF** o **While** en VB de excel, para cuando se cumpla la condición ejecute una macro y cierre el workbook y la aplicación.

Por el momento tengo el siguiente código:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("7:00 AM"), CopiarPegarCambium
 End Sub
```

Comment: Pero tal cual lo quieres plantear, implica dejar la macro y Excel ejecutándose permanentemente hasta que se cumpla la hora especificada. ¿No es mejor que ejecutes una tarea de Windows que abra el archivo (o lo cierre) a una hora concreta?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes eso ya lo hace. pero no se como cerrar el archivo y Excel. lo hago desde un archivo **.bat**. ese archivo solo habre excel.

Comment: Desde VBA con puedes cerrar el archivo con `ThisWorkbook.Close`. O si no, desde otro BAT con un task kill

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Excelente. gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas por el buen camino.
De hecho, el código que has escrito salvo por una cosa funcionaría.

[Método OnTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.OnTime) 

 Si ves los detalles del método *OnTime*, ejecuta un procedimiento a una fecha y/u hora del día.
El único error en el códig oque puedo ver comparando con el ejemplo de MS, es que el nombre del procedimiento a ejecutar debe estar como escrito como una cadena de caracteres o String, entre comillas dobles tal que así:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.OnTime TimeValue("7:00 AM"), "CopiarPegarCambium"
 End Sub
```

Así que cuando habras la hoja, se programará esta acción a esa hora y cuando lelgue el momento se ejecutará el procedimiento.

Con lo cual, no veo porque necesitas un *IF* o un *WHILE*, no te hacen falta, a no ser que quieras que se cumpla otra condición que no tenga que ver con la hora.